# Axes Disappearing and failed to register on Click Matlab

Tags: matlab

I've been having an issue where in my figure part of the axes will disappear and stop registering. I have a pretty complex gui so I tried to replicate the issue with a smaller gui. I was able to replicate it in part and I don't know if it will fix the original issue, but hopefully it's a start. The only thing that consistently causes the original issue is screen resolution which is really weird to me.

Here is the code used to create the figure:

```
f = figure('MenuBar','none','ButtonDownFcn','f.CurrentObject');
a = axes('Parent',f);
plot(a,[1 4 9 16 25]);
```

I can't show images so you'll have to trust me -_-
When I click on the figure and not the axes, it displays:

```
f = 
  Figure (1) with properties:

  Number: 1
    Name: ''
   Color: [0.9400 0.9400 0.9400]
Position: [403 246 560 420]
   Units: 'pixels'

Show all properties
```

and not when I click on the axes, which makes sense.

When I enlarge the figure the bottom and right sides of the axes start to crop and when the white of the axes is click on (not the beige figure) the callback responds and says the CurrentObject is the figure and not the axes. The units are normalized by default but I have tried with characters to no avail.

**Maximised:**
[image: screenshot1]

**Not maximised:**
[image: screenshot1]

Update:
I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and MATLAB 2015A
However my co-worker had the identical behavior when running the code on Windows 8 with MATLAB 2015A

Comment: I followed the steps with the provided example code and did not experience this behavior.

Comment: There is no callback registered on the axes, so the statement `f.CurrentObject` will never be executed when you click on the `axes`. If you click on the `axes` then execute the statement in your workspace you will see the `current object`is indeed the `axes`. Other than that, like @excaza, I do not have cropping/resizing issue as you describe.

Comment: I left the callback on the axes out so that it would only display a message in the command window when the figure was clicked. I think if I could show the screenshots it would help...The problem  arises when the figure is enlarged on a 1920x1200 monitor. On my laptop monitor (1366x768) it does not occur. These numbers aren't hard numbers where the issue happens, but for me the figure maximized gets cropped on the large monitor (it's dual display)

Comment: Got links to the images to show you what's happening on my screen
http://imgur.com/DpLkBU6,9sZnOZG
The first is when it's maximized and the second is when it's not. See how the first one is cropped on the bottom right and left? This also effects whether or not it registers the axes as the CurrentObject (top level) for me

Comment: I've had various surprises with the way Matlab detects Linux desktop and multi-monitors. I will let the linux pro chime in but I suspect a discrepancy between how Matlab and the OS interprets the multi desktop layout. _You should specify your Linux and Matlab version_.

Comment: We found a work-around by limiting the max size the window can be when resizing. Any way through SO I can think you guys for your help/time? (pretty new to SO, I only know how to accept answers but I don't have a solid answer to this exact issue so it wouldn't help the community to post a non-sense answer...)